# django slugify thailand umlauts

Tags: django, slug, slugify

i need to create Thai language slug but after i use slugify not working

Models.py

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

title = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80,unique=True,allow_unicode=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import category,Blog

class BlogAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}

admin.site.register(category)
admin.site.register(Blog,BlogAdmin)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVgJd.png)

i need : slug = สวัสดีครับ ยินดีที่ได้รู้จัก

but not : slug = สวสดครบ-ยนดทไดรจก

if i input สวัสดีครับ ยินดีที่ได้รู้จัก to slug error alert " Enter a valid “slug” consisting of Unicode letters, numbers, underscores, or hyphens. "

how i can fix it